# Backup current folder with date added to the filenames

Tags: macos, command-line, backup

Working on the Windows PC, I've used the cmd file with the following line:

```
winrar.exe a -agYYYYMMDD -x*\*.cmd -r -ibck -ep1 -ed "%~dp0..\_materials\bak - .rar" *.*
```

It helped me to create backups of the current folder with date added to the filename and with some particular files excluded.

How could I have the same on OS X? I would be OK with zip instead of rar.

Upd. Here is explanation what winrar was doing with this arguments:

- **a** - add to archive
- **-agYYYYMMDD** - add current date to the archive file in the format YYYYMMDD
- **-x*\*.cmd** - exclude all cmd files from the result archive
- **-r** - include all subfolders and files there
- **-ibck** - run in background
- **-ep1** - exclude current folder from the archive
- **-ed** - exclude empty folders

(and here is winrar for mac os - http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarosx-5.0.1.tar.gz)

Comment: Of course you can do the same on OS X. Do you need a file that will be executed upon double-click? For those of us who don't have `winrar.exe` (or a Windows PC, that is), what exactly do you need to get? Could you include an example of how filenames should look like before and after backup? Should the directory hierarchy be retained or will the command run non-recursively?

Comment: @slhck, yes, I am looking for the file to be executed upon double click. I've tried to answer your other questions in my updated question (winrar.exe is archiver like zip).

Comment: @slhck, what is used instead of cmd on mac? Please show me the direction, no need to create this backup script :). Thanks.

Comment: On OS X you'd use *Terminal.app* to open a Bash session. Sorry I don't have time to check this out in more detail for you.

Comment: @slhck, this is clear that I can use Terminal like command line on Windows. But how can I create batch files to run commands automatically on file double click?